# Ansible - ssh error message when deploying a playbook

Tags: ansible

Here is the error message I get when I launch a playbook?

From the server, the ssh connection is made with the key.

Do you have an idea?

fatal: [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Connection timed out during banner exchange", "unreachable": true}

ansible v.17

Comment: Are you able to connect to the server successfully from the command line?

Comment: Yes, from the server I connect in ssh to the bastion via an ssh key and once on the bastion I connect to the final server.


I have another awx server in an old version or there is no problem, I cannot find the setting that is causing the problem for my new server.

Comment: If you run Ansible with `-vvv` you will see the exact `ssh` command line it's using to connect. Compare this to what you're running manually and that may shed some light on things. If you update your question to include the ssh command line from the `-vvv` output, along with an example successful command line, we can try to help figure things out.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for this feedback. I am using ansible with docker and the web interface, is it possible to use the -vvv function from through the web interface?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the web interface you're using, sorry.

Comment: The problem was with the firewall. Thank you for your feedback.